# How do you turn an array into a list or how can you set up an array to be used in stickyheaders?

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

I have a set of data in an array and would like to turn it into a list or added the data to a list. The stickyheaders library uses lists and I need to change mine into a list since I'm having difficulty in using the stickyheaders as arrays it only shows a blank recyclerview.

This is my set of sample data, this is data is just used for creating a new event in a calendar. I retrieve the day and format it to show (e.g Monday). This is what the header will be.

If anyone can help turning this array into a list or how to add these data to a list, it would be appreciated, or if someone is familiar with stickyheaders and used arrays for it some sample code is appreciated.

```
public static final Event[] EventList = {
    new Event("The Theory of Everything", "1:00 PM", "Cinema 1", 2015, 2, 5, 13, 0),
    new Event("Kingsman the Secret Service", "3:00 PM", "Cinema 2", 2015, 2, 5, 15, 0),
    new Event("Fifty Shades of Grey", "5:00 PM", "Cinema 3", 2015, 2, 5, 17, 0),
    new Event("Focus", "7:00 PM", "Cinema 4", 2015, 2, 5, 19, 0),
    new Event("Crazy Beautiful You", "9:00 PM", "Cinema 5", 2015, 2, 5, 21, 0),
    new Event("The Theory of Everything", "1:00 PM", "Cinema 1", 2015, 2, 6, 13, 0),
    new Event("Kingsman the Secret Service", "3:00 PM", "Cinema 2", 2015, 2, 6, 15, 0),
    new Event("Fifty Shades of Grey", "5:00 PM", "Cinema 3", 2015, 2, 6, 17, 0),
    new Event("Focus", "7:00 PM", "Cinema 4", 2015, 2, 6, 19, 0),
    new Event("Crazy Beautiful You", "9:00 PM", "Cinema 5", 2015, 2, 6, 21, 0)
};
```

Comment: See first attempt can be made through Arrays.aslist(your array). But this is am saying because i'm unaware about your Event class.

Comment: Is your Event class a native android class ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. After that you can do:

```
List<Event> eventList = Arrays.asList(EventList);
```